# Nodeenv installation error: OSError: Command make --jobs=2 failed with error code 2

Tags: python, node.js, virtualenv

I'm trying to install `nodeenv` from within `virtualenv`, but something goes terribly wrong. I'm running Debian 7 (Wheezy).

Here's what I've done:

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages ENV
source ENV/bin/activate
(ENV) pip install nodeenv
(ENV) nodeenv NODEENV
```

In response I get the following message:

```
* Install node (4.0.0)..
```

... it gets stuck there for ~10 minutes, then curses:

```
File "/home/bob/Documents/Projects/xyz/ENV/bin/nodeenv", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('nodeenv==0.13.6', 'console_scripts', 'nodeenv')()
File "/home/bob/Documents/Projects/xyz/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nodeenv.py", line 891, in main
create_environment(env_dir, opt)
File "/home/bob/Documents/Projects/xyz/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nodeenv.py", line 732, in create_environment
install_node(env_dir, src_dir, opt)
File "/home/bob/Documents/Projects/xyz/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nodeenv.py", line 608, in install_node
build_node_from_src(env_dir, src_dir, node_src_dir, opt)
File "/home/bob/Documents/Projects/xyz/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nodeenv.py", line 577, in build_node_from_src
callit([make_cmd] + make_opts, opt.verbose, True, node_src_dir, env)
File "/home/bob/Documents/Projects/xyz/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nodeenv.py", line 461, in callit
% (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command make --jobs=2 failed with error code 2
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

**WORKAROUND:**

`ekalinin` suggested at [github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv/issues/136](http://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv/issues/136) to use `nodeenv -p --prebuilt` command to install node right in the python virtual environment. For some reason, it doesn't produce the bug.

Comment: Did you solve? I have the same: workon myenv && pip install nodeenv && nodeenv -p I got OSError: Command ./configure --prefix=/srv/virtualenvs/myenv failed with error code 1

Comment: @Daviddd I used a workaround, suggested by ekalinin at https://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv/issues/136: used `nodeenv -p --prebuilt` command to install node right in the python virtual environment. For some reason, it doesn't produce the bug.